# I am getting a cors error even though I have defined a .net 6.0 cors policy

Tags: c#, .net, web, cors, policy

I don't get a cors error when I run it locally. but when i publish on hosting i get cors error.

error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'https://mp3-api.batuhanfindik.com/api/User/Login' from origin
> 'https://www.batuhanfindik.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

code:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy => {
    policy.WithOrigins(new[] { 
                                "https://www.batuhanfindik.com", 
                                "https://batuhanfindik.com",
                                "http://www.batuhanfindik.com",
                                "http://batuhanfindik.com",
                                "https://www.mp3-api.batuhanfindik.com", 
                                "https://mp3-api.batuhanfindik.com", 
                                "http://www.mp3-api.batuhanfindik.com", 
                                "http://mp3-api.batuhanfindik.com", 
                                "https://localhost:3000", 
                                "https://172.34.1.78:3000", 
                                "https://localhost:3001" 
                              })
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials();                   
}));

app.UseCors(options =>
    options.WithOrigins(new[] {
                                "https://www.batuhanfindik.com",
                                "https://batuhanfindik.com",
                                "http://www.batuhanfindik.com",
                                "http://batuhanfindik.com",
                                "https://www.mp3-api.batuhanfindik.com",
                                "https://mp3-api.batuhanfindik.com",
                                "http://www.mp3-api.batuhanfindik.com",
                                "http://mp3-api.batuhanfindik.com",
                                "https://localhost:3000",
                                "https://172.34.1.78:3000",
                                "https://localhost:3001"
                              })
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowCredentials()
                );
```

only in api sub domain. The site the user entered is in the main domain. interface master domain. api subdomain.

Now I fixed it somehow. but this time i don't get cors error from my computer. When I enter from other devices, it gives a cors error.

Comment: @NotFound As you said, what should I do if the hosting company uses cors?

Answer (score -1):

Please try this once.

```
private static readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
    
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
        build =>
        {
            build.WithOrigins('url-here').AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
```

Comment: unfortunately it didn't happen

Comment: is `app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);` and `app.UseAuthentication();` presented on your code?

Comment: Yeah. I just wrote the string expression directly into add.policy because I couldn't define a variable in program.cs

Comment: @Batuhan you can define a variable if you add namespace and class and write the entire code into `public static void main(string[] args)` method

Comment: I created it now but it still didn't work

Comment: Now I fixed it somehow. but this time i don't get cors error from my computer. When I enter from other devices, it gives a cors error.

Answer (score -2):

I solved on my project using the following code.

On the startup.cs file in the `public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)`

Add the following line after `app.UseRouting`

```cs
app.UseCors(
    options => options.SetIsOriginAllowed(x => _ = true).AllowAnyMethod().WithHeaders(new[] { $"{headersStandard}, {headersLowered}" }).AllowCredentials()
);
```

I set custom headers so I need to set cors accordingly thus the (with headers)

Then in the `public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` method add the following line after `services.AddControllers();`

```cs
services.AddCors();
```

Comment: Now I fixed it somehow. but this time i don't get cors error from my computer. When I enter from other devices, it gives a cors error.

Comment: Are you sending custom headers? If so you need to specify those headers in the CORS I was unable to use AllowAnyHeader on .net6

Comment: Axios.post('https://localhost:7024/api/'+url, value,{ withCredentials: true })).data; 
this is how i send it.